# Using History.js with mod_rewritten URLs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, history.js

I have a search page located at http://www.example.com/search_result.php, and I'm mod_rewriting it to be http://www.example.com/search-result.

Basically, I want to do what the [History.js demo](http://balupton.github.com/history.js/demo/) does - append an arbitrary string to the end of the URL (with a `#` if it's a HTML4 browser). The demo works great in my browser's - however, my site's `<base>` tag points to the root directory on all pages, and I think that's what's breaking my site's behaviour.

Here's what happens: If my rewritten URL ends with a `/`, HTML4 browsers go into an infinite URL loop of appending the string to the end of the URL. If it doesn't, I lose the `search-result` portion of my URL in HTML5 browsers, and adding `"search-result/` to the statement also adds it after the `#` in HTML4 browsers.

And If I change the base tag, the page looks for its files (CSS, JS, images, everything) in the nonexistent directory of `/search-result/`. So I'm screwed.

So, how do I fix this? Or should I be looking for another library? There's RSH, but it hasn't been updated since 2007...

Comment: Thought about a) re-referencing your assets (CSS, JS, ...) absolutely or b) rewriting them with mod_rewrite?

Comment: You don't need `<base>`, if you reference your scripts/css/images with absolute paths.  For example `/scripts/myscript.js` `/style/mystyle.css`.

Comment: Changing all the references in the site would be a lot of work. I guess a temporary solution would be a putting different base href for the search-result page (the only place where I use History.js) + mod_rewriting any resources requested in the /search-result/ directory. Perhaps I should use the 404 page to try and serve them. But it's an ugly hack, and I'd prefer something more graceful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you use something like this where you exclude specific directories from the rewrite?

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(scripts|styles|images)
RewriteRule your-rewrite-rule-here [L]
```

Comment: That would've helped. I ended up prepending a backslash to everything (which really wasn't as much work as I expected it to be), but I'll keep this in mind.